# How can I reconfig synergy on mac after starting it as server by mistake?

Tags: macos, mac, synergy

I'm new to mac. I just installed synergy and run it as server by mistake. It automatically minimized and I cannot find it again. I tried to drag the app to trash and reinstall but it will start as the same configuration as server just like before.

How can I find a way to configure it back to client mode?
I cannot find synergy.conf anywhere in my mac.

Thanks

Comment: uninstall the package and then install it again?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the synergy 'circle' in the menu-bar, select 'show' and then Synergy should be accessible as a normal app window (CMD-TAB to the circle icon). In the configuration window you should be able to deselect the 'server' setting and set up the client setting..